# JUnit testing in Android Studio with Kotlin stopped working

Tags: junit4, kotlin, android-studio-2.2

I have a project in Android Studio where I created a java library module. In there I have a Kotlin class which I want to test. When I create the test in Kotlin and try to run it, the IDE keeps telling me:

Process finished with exit code 1
Class not found: "com.example.CacheTest" Empty test suite.

When I create the same test in Java everything works fine.

I created tests in other projects in Kotlin as well and there it works.

I recently update AS to 2.2.2 and use Kotlin 1.0.4

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have this in your `build.gradle`?

```
sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    test.java.srcDirs += 'src/test/kotlin'
}

dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Directory structure like:

[image]

and a test class:

```
import org.junit.Assert
import org.junit.Test

class TestCase {

    @Test fun someTest(){
        Assert.assertFalse(true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Well at the moment I have the Kotlin files also in the java folder so the sourceSets should not be needed if I'm not mistaken. Other than that I have the same.

Comment: It is very strange, it always worked so far in other projects. I really wonder if the AS update has something to do with it.

Comment: @Marc_Bob I don't think so. I have the most recent version of AS and everything is fine.

Comment: I've got the same issue. Android studio 3.0 + Gradle 3.0 + Kotlin 1.1.51.